# Exception: The file or folder has invalid access settings. (line 31, file "newfile")

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

```
var holderArray = [
  folder.getId(),
  folder.getName(),
  folder.getOwner(),
  folderPath,
  folder.getDateCreated(),
  folder.getLastUpdated(),
  folder.getAccess(user),
  folder.getSharingAccess(),
  folder.getSharingPermission(),
  folder.getUrl()
];
```

For some reason, this above line is causing an error saying I have invalid access settings. 
I am not sure why this is happening. I have specified which folder to access and I have also given access to my Drive folder as well.

Comment: What is the content of line 31? Please provide all of your relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this.. The solution was that if you want to log all the information of all your folders and files then you have to make sure that you do not use `folder.getAccess(user), folder.getSharingAccess(), folder.getSharingPermission()`
if you use the above lines of code you will receive the same warning when trying to log all files and folders that are shared with you in your GDrive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code in an onOpen() or onEdit() function GS will throw this error.
The logic is that those functions can run for anyone that has access to the sheet but they may not have acces to your google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. I put the folder.getSharingAccess() and folder.getSharingPermission() functions in try-catch block and then continued the process. Since it was in try-catch block I was able to identify the problematic files and folders. After I identified the files or folders with the error, I checked them and realised that their sharing link showed the following message "Links vary" then another screen opened showing different access rights for different groups with separate links. As soon as I changed to a single group with a single link it was all fine.